# Dyanamic Datatable when number of rows is variable

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, datatables

I have a an ajax call that returns a JSON object containing the data I wish to be displayed in the data table and I am displaying it like this:

```
  returnresult['DATA'].forEach( function (row) {
                                                        tableLogData.row.add({"0": row[0],
                                                                              "1": row[1],
                                                                              "2": row[2],
                                                                              "3": row[3],
                                                                              "4": row[4]}).draw( false );
                                                    })
```

Which works and displays this (Ignore the headers they arent in any order):

[image]

The issue is that sometimes the data I need to display is more or less than the 5 rows that I have hard coded in. So how does one account for a variable number of rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already accounting for a variable number of rows. To account for a variable number of columns, you just need another loop.

Change

```
tableLogData.row.add({
    "0": row[0],
    "1": row[1],
    "2": row[2],
    "3": row[3],
    "4": row[4]
}).draw( false );
```

to

```
const rowData = {};
for (let i in row) {
    rowData[i] = row[i];
}
tableLogData.row.add(rowData).draw( false );
```

Comment: This is really cool I would not have thought to do this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you used a const? and what exactly does setting const rowData equal to {} do? I'm sorry I'm I've never used data tables before and I'm trying to learn as much as I can.

Comment: Either way (hard coded or using a loop) we are passing an object with row data to the `add` function. `const rowData = {};` just creates an empty object so we can then add a key value pair for each row. Once we've filled `rowData`, we pass it to `add` the same way we did when the object was hard coded.

Comment: `const` is the same as `let` except you are also saying "hey computer, I intend this variable to be constant so don't let me reassign it later". In other words `rowData = 1;` or anything else that sets `rowData` to something new will show up as an error in the javascript. `const` vs `let` is not important here. You can change it to `let` if it's confusing.